# react is it possible to fire function implemnted on one child from another child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 3 components:

1. Parent
2. Child1
3. Child2 - not really a react component(it's a component that uses 3rd javascript library that manipulates the DOM directly and does not managed by React.
   this component never renders and mutates only on componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps)

I wish to trigger function(lets call her 'triggerCallback') from Child1 on Child2.
The implementation of triggerCallback must be on Child2 because it mutates vars of Child2(vars that i don't want to be managed by Parent's state!).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const Child1 = props => {
  return <button onClick={props.triggerCallback}>Click Me</button>;
};

class Child2 extends Component {
  data = [];

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(receviedProps) {
      // here I need to add a prop or a callback notification to fire 'triggerCallback', how?
  }

  triggerCallback = action => {
    console.log("i triggerd from Child1!");
    // here mutate data!
  };

  // componentDidMount() {} and some extra methods.....

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
const Parent = props => {
  // how do i pass function implemnted on Child2 to be called from Child1?
  return (
    <div>
      <Child1 />
      <Child2 />
    </div>
  );
};
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: so pass a callback to the child from the parent. when clicked on the child, parent sets a state, that state value is passed to the other child. On the other child when getting the updated prop value you can trigger a method call.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). Please note that I couldn't try my example, so consider it as a kind of pseudocode

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const Child1 = props => {
  return <button onClick={props.triggerCallback}>Click Me</button>;
};

class Child2 extends Component {
  data = [];

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
  }

  constructor(props) {
      // Feed the function in the setter revieved as props
      super(props);
      props.getCallBack(this.triggerCallback);
  }

  triggerCallback = action => {
    console.log("i triggerd from Child1!");
    // here mutate data!
  };

  // componentDidMount() {} and some extra methods.....

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
const Parent = props => {
  // Use a state that contains child2's function or an empty callback
  const [func, setFunc] = React.useState(() => void(0));
  // send setter as props to child2
  return (
    <div>
      <Child1 triggerCallback={func} />
      <Child2 getCallBack={(cb) => {setFunc(cb);}} />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: wow this was a great idea!
but apparently this is not possible to change function on one component from another one:
"Warning: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component." I think that is not possible to implement what I wanted in this way and will need to do it in another approach

Comment: @EliavLouski maybe i think the problem is with the useState being called during rendereding, you could try doing let func = () => void(0); then in the getCallBack={(cb) => {func = cb;}}


Alternatively you could use a [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)